# Global buffer overflow during .text segment parsing

Tags: android, memory-management, overflow, elf, address-sanitizer

Given the code attached, and related to this issue '[Global buffer overflow during .text section parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77911663/global-buffer-overflow-during-text-section-parsing)', I want to know if this code could be modified to only parse the .text section in memory (the executable code) to avoid global buffer overflow with ASAN.

```
extern char __ehdr_start;
extern char etext;

ElfW(Ehdr) *elfhdr = (ElfW(Ehdr) *) &__ehdr_start;
int i;
    
for (i = 3; (unsigned long)(&__ehdr_start + elfhdr->e_entry + i) < (unsigned long)(&etext); i = i + 4) {
        if ((unsigned char)*(&__ehdr_start + elfhdr->e_entry + i) == 0x01 ) {
            
            if(((unsigned char)*(&__ehdr_start + elfhdr->e_entry + i - 1) == 0x02) && ((unsigned char)*(&__ehdr_start + elfhdr->e_entry + i - 2) == 0x03) && ((unsigned char)*(&__ehdr_start + elfhdr->e_entry + i - 3) == 0x04)) {
        ....
```

Parse the .text section of Android application native code without the ASAN crash for Global buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Global buffer overflow during .text segment parsing

In your other question, you were parsing `.text` *segment*. In this question you are attempting to parse `.text` *section*. The titles of your questions are swapped.

Your modified code here doesn't actually parse the `.text` section. It starts scanning from (usually) the `_start` symbol, and stops when reaching `etext` symbol.

There are two assumptions here:

- the `_start` symbol is at the beginning of the `.text` section and
- everything between `_start` and `etext` is coming from `.text` section

Neither of these assumptions is guaranteed to be true, although *usually* they are on Linux. I have no idea what a typical Android binary layout is.

You should be able to run `nm --numeric-sort a.out` and look at all the symbols between `_start` and `etext`. If any of them are in the `{C,D,G,R,S,V}` set (or same set in lowercase), then the second assumption is violated.

If all symbols are `T`, `t`, `W` or `w`, probably something else is going on. But you should be able to *tell* what's going on since you know which address between `_start` and `etext` is triggering AddressSanitizer error and which symbol is at that address.